# Shuffling method "Unreachable code detected"

Tags: c#, .net, methods

The problem given is

> we have an array, we have to shuffle it. run a loop 100 times, find two random elements every loop and swap them

The problem in the code is in the for loop - it says "i++" is unreachable.
The actual swapping code works, as if I remove the loop and just run the lines of randomizing indexes and swapping them works well. As soon as I introduce the loop, I get "unreachable code detected" for the i++ in the for loop. Code still runs, but still only swaps once as the loop was never there.

```
int[] Shuffle(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.Next(array.Length);
        int y = r.Next(array.Length);
        (array[x], array[y]) = (array[y], array[x]);
        return array;
    }
    return array;
}
```

How can I get this to swap two random numbers 100 times before actually returning the shuffled array?

Comment: You have a `return` statement right at the end of the loop body. This means the loop will only run 1 time, and the index increment statement will never be executed. You probably need the `return` only after the 100 iterations are done.

Comment: Apart from anything else. Don't create the `Random` object inside the loop. It shouldn't even be created inside the method.

Comment: Adding to what @jmcilhinney said, if you are using .NET 6 or higher just use `Random.Shared`.